# Unable to put active in particular ul li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am having the ul li structure as:

```
         <ul class="sidebar-menu">
            <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
            <li class="active treeview">
              <a href="#">
                <span>Dashboard</span>
              </a>
              <ul class="treeview-menu">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Dashboard v1</a></li>
                <li><a href="index2.php">Dashboard v2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="treeview">
              <a href="#">
                <span>Layout Options</span>
                <span class="label label-primary pull-right">4</span>
              </a>
              <ul class="treeview-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Top Navigation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Boxed</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fixed</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Collapsed Sidebar</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
```

What i tried is

```
    $(".sidebar-menu ul li a").on("click", function() {
        $(".active treeview")
            .not($(this).parents('li'))
                .removeClass('active treeview');
        $(this)
            .parent()
                .addClass('active treeview')
                .find("ul.treeview")
                    .stop("true", "true")
                    .slideDown()
                    .addClass('active');
        $(this)
            .parent()
                .siblings()
                    .find("ul.treeview")
                        .stop("true", "true")
                        .slideUp()
                        .removeClass('active');
    });
```

Here the class 'active treeview' shows the Main menu as active and class `active` shows sub menu active.

i tried using javascript to remove all other classes, the classes get removed but when adding class to the particular `li` it do not works. how to write the java script when i click on some menu it shows that sub menu and his parent is activated.

Comment: Please could you show us what you tried?

Comment: Please update your question with what you have tried using javascript

Comment: @Salketer  I have updated my code

Comment: Would you mind include your demo code in jsfiddle since the code does not work when I try?

Answer (score 0):

**try this one**

> works for both side menu and treeview

```
    /** add active class and stay opened when selected */
var url = window.location;

// for sidebar menu entirely but not cover treeview
$('ul.sidebar-menu a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url;
}).parent().siblings().removeClass('active').end().addClass('active');

// for treeview
$('ul.treeview-menu a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url;
}).parentsUntil(".sidebar-menu > .treeview-menu").siblings().removeClass('active').end().addClass('active');
```